# cannot initialize a variable of type 'std::terminate_handler' (aka 'void (*)()') from libsupc++ library

Tags: c++, embedded, clang

I'm trying to compile libsupc++ with a clang. I got this error in file libsupc++/eh_term_handler.cc:45:36

I've tried to typecast the before initializing. But I'm not understanding 'void (*)()' data type.

```cpp
/* The current installed user handler.  */
std::terminate_handler __cxxabiv1::__terminate_handler =
 #if _GLIBCXX_HOSTED
            __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler;
    #else
            abort();
    #endif
```

---

```
CC  lib/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_unex_handler.o
    lib/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_term_handler.cc:45:36: error: cannot initialize
          a variable of type 'std::terminate_handler' (aka 'void (*)()') with an rvalue of type 'void'
    std::terminate_handler __cxxabiv1::__terminate_handler =

                                           ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: My guess is that `_GLIBCXX_HOSTED` isn't defined.

Comment: Also since this is tagged embedded, it might be a freestanding system and not a hosted one?

Comment: Where did you get that from? The [gcc mirror](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/eh_term_handler.cc) on github has no version that looks like that. The most similar implementation is 16 years old, but that one says `std::abort;`, as one would expect.

Comment: @Lundin yes it is freestanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that `std::terminate_handler` is a function pointer of type `void(*)()` and you can't initialize such a function pointer with `void`. In this case, `void` is what's returned from the function call `abort();`

Plainly, change `abort();` (function call) to `abort;` (function designator).

Comment: I got it from some old kernel. I guess I'll have to add an updated library. Thanks that solved my problem but generate other more errors.